# ngFor object in click event

Tags: angular

I'm working on an application which shows a list of elements (with ngFor) which also have an "add" Button. When clicking on a button, the element should be shown in a separate list:

```html
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let trooper of impalasum">
        {{trooper.name}} <button id="btn_{{trooper.name}}" (click)="addToList({{trooper}})">Add</button>
    </li>
</ul> 
<hr>
<ul>
    <li>{{addedTrooper.name}} -> XY</li>
</ul>
```

```ts
addToList(troop: Trooper): void{
    this.addedTrooper = troop;
}
```

I want to have the trooper as a parameter in the click event, but this way it doesn't work. So how can I do that?

Comment: `(click)="addToList(trooper)"`

Comment: You may try (click)="addToList(trooper)"

Comment: You should read about event binding vs model binding in angular. Simple to understand, very hard to figure out what's going on within an app until you do this though :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Don't use interpolation within output binding

```
(click)="addToList(trooper)"
```